# Chris Pine Ruby ch 10, recursion

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have been trying to learn ruby using the book 'learn to program' by Chris Pine. I was actually getting excited when going through the book until I got to chapter 10 and the examples used. Now this chapter alone and its examples have completely deflated all of my excitement to continue with this book. In this example I have completely no idea how its trying to count the tiles, or why he uses world [y],[x] when the method was defined with the attribute of continent_size world, x,y? Im not sure how the recursion in this example works. Can someone shed some more light onto this example as to what the author was actually trying to do?

```
M = 'land'
o = 'water'

world = [
  [o,o,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o],
  [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
  [o,o,o,o,o,M,o,o,M,M,o],
  [o,o,o,M,o,M,o,o,o,M,o],
  [o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
  [o,o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o],
  [M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M],
  [o,o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o],
  [o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o],
  [o,M,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
  [o,o,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o]]

def continent_size world, x ,y

  if x < 0 or x > 10 or y < 0 or y > 10
    return 0
  end

  if world[y][x] != 'land'
    return 0
  end

  size = 1
  world [y][x] = 'counted land'

  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x , y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y )
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y )
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y+1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x , y+1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y+1)
  size

end

puts continent_size(world, 5, 5)
```

Comment: This program and chapter is just not clicking. I feel like i get a grasp on recursion but then look at this code and get confused and frustrated. Can someone walk me through the code and explain what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a flood fill.  What it's doing is counting the size of all the pieces of 'land' that are connected to the initial starting point.  Note that it doesn't count all of the 'land' symbols, just the ones on that it can't get to because of water.

Flood fill is a form of something called depth first search which is a way to traverse a graph (here, a discrete 'map').  It can be summarized like so:

1. Visit the current position/graph node, count it and mark it as visited
2. Check all connected nodes (here, anything up, down, left or right), if they are not visited and they are land, recursively visit them

He might be doing y, x for the following reason: the logical format of a 2D array is organized first by row, then by column.  The row could be thought of as the y axis and the column as the x.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I when I worked through this problem in the book I also noticed the transposition of x & y when world is called.   I looked on the Pragmatic Programmer's website to see if this was listed in the errata, but it is not.

I thought it was typo and flipped them to x, y.  The code works either way.

It doesn't really matter, since the starting point of 5,5 is arbitrary and the code will check all eight tiles around x,y (or y,x) regardless until it hits the "edge" of the array/world.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a few steps back from the other answers, the recursion here is in that `continent_size` is called eight times from within `continent_size`.

So the method is being called eight times inside itself.

But ... each of those eight inner methods call `continent_size` a further eight times.

And so on, and so on.

It's bonkers to get your head around it, but when you do, it feels like you can see The Matrix. Albeit very briefly.

I stumbled across this question looking for some help with the extension bit of the task (how to avoid the error if one of your 'explorers' falls off the edge of the world).

I ended up solving this with a rescue:

```
# If it's off the edge of the world, it's as good as water
square = world[y][x] rescue 'o'

if square != 'Land'
  return 0
end
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it seems quite elegant to me.

Comment: While your solution works, technically, if it's water you are replacing the edge of the world by, then it should be the variable `o`, not the character `'o'`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty dirty about the way I solved it, and am here looking for a better answer. I created a new variable, E = 'edge', and changed any character that touched the edge of the map to E. Then I added this code to the top of the continent_size method:

```
if world[y][x] == 'edge'
        return 1
    end
```

It works. :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rescue approach still crashes when the top edge of the world is all 'o's. A simple approach to solving this is to write a conditional that checks if either coordinate (x,y) is outside of the boundary (i.e. outside of 0 or world.length-1) and return 0 if that condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed the transposition of x and y in Pine's code.
   I think the reasoning might be that he arranged the "world" array so that there is one sub-array on each line.  The first number in square brackets following "world"  (world[0]) refers to the index of the element (sub-array) within world.  Since these are stacked vertically it is your y-axis.  The second bracketed number (world[0][5]) refers to the element within the sub-array.  These run horizontally so the second number refers to your x-axis.  Writing the method to take parameter x then parameter y allows you to enter the staring location in the conventional (x,y) format while within the method the variables are transposed to accomplish the task.  I think.  I'm completely new to this though.

Also, if anyone has a clean solution to extended version of this exercise where where the continent "borders the edge of the world" I would love to see it

Comment: Answered my own question about the extended exercise.  I added one 'if' statement at the top of the method that checks whether the (x,y) coordinate is within the "map" boundaries.                  'if y+1>world.length || x+1>world[y].length
return 0
end'

Answer (score 0):

It also took me some time to get the head around this example. I tried to solve the task like this, at first:

```
  if ( world[y] > world[y].length  || world[x] > world[x].length ) || ( world[y] < world[y].length || world[x] < world[x].length )
    return 0 
  end
```

But I kept getting errors of the "undefined method ">" for an array"

I then realised that the solution could be in conditioning "x" and "y", if they are more than an array (10) or lower than (0):

```
if x > 10 || x < 0 || y > 10 || y < 0
  return 0
end
```

The problem here is that it works on this particular size of arrays...if the world is bigger than 10 - the program would count every "land" it encounters as 0.

So I guess it's half-solution only...